# Playing audio based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

i'm trying to get an audio file played when the screen is at least 1600px.
This is my HTML

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay></audio>
```

and my jQuery

```
var width = $(window).width();

function audio() {
    $("#audio").attr("src","zoubisou.mp3");
    $("#audio").attr("type","audio/mp3");
    $("#audio").trigger("play");
}

if (width > 1600) {
    audio();
}
```

It won't play anything. I even tried to get the audio element by it's ID and append to it the source element with the attributes listed above. Won't work either.

The logic behind this is to make the sound play only on desktop browsers, and not tablet/mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code playing sound based on window width..  [jsfiddle  playing sound](http://jsfiddle.net/jTh3v/94/)

```
function audio() {
    $("#audio").attr("src","http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"); 
    $("#audio").trigger("play");
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var width = $(window).width();
    $("#widthwin").html("window width is " + width);
    if (width > 500) {
        audio();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, seems the problem with my code was the "type" attr